# Android Studio: can no longer see dependencies javadoc

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, rx-java, javadoc

Android Studio v3.0 Canary 4,
but happens for me on Android Studio v2.3.3 too

I'm not sure since when this started to happen, what version or configuration I've made (if any), but I can no longer see libraries/dependencies javadoc:

for instance, RxJava:

[image]

Even though, Android SDK **does** **show** the javadocs correctly:

[image]

This is true for all libs I have, I looked everywhere on the net for this issue, and it seems like I'm the only one.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can manually specify JavaDoc.

Navigate to jar file, select "Library Properties",  click "Specify Documentation URL".

For RxJava 2.x: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/

For RxJava 1.x: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/1.x/javadoc/

[image]

Detailed how-to can be found [here](https://medium.com/@mydogtom/tip-how-to-attach-javadoc-to-the-library-in-android-studio-5ff43c4303b3)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. Allegedly it was fixed last month, but from what I've seen some extra monkeying is needed to get the correct behavior back - I downloaded the latest Android O artifacts from the SDK Manager, then temporarily changed all build.gradle settings to support Android O, then switched back, and now I see the javadoc again even without supporting O. Here's the bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37140074

Comment: this didnt help.
One thing is wierd though - if i open a new project, with the same gradle & gadle plugin versions, javadocs does appear!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do as a workaround is to inspect a class in the dependency, and it'll give you the decompiled byte code with an option to "Download...". Click that, source is downloaded, and now you have javadocs. You have to do this for each dependency, but it persists through cleans and resyncs.